# Redirect whit htaccess (guion at begin and end)

Tags: .htaccess

I need to redirect

```
http://mysite.com/mp3/-angel-la-pared-shakira-/
```

to this

```
http://mysite.com/mp3/angel-la-pared-shakira/
```

this is my htaccess

```
RewriteEngine on  
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f  
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d  
RewriteRule ^mp3/(.*)/$ search.php?q=$1
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule (.*)\.xml sitemap.php [nocase]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^.*[^/]$ /$0/ [L,R=301]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add this to the *beginning* of your htaccess file:

```
RewriteRule ^mp3/-([^/]+)-/$ /mp3/$1/ [L,R=301]
```